# Vue+Nuxt extended router gives 404 content instead of last page visited

Tags: vue.js, navigation, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, router

I have the following router set up in nuxt.config.js so that I can add external links to a v-list-item.

In nuxt.config.js:

```js
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes,resolve) {
    routes.push({
      // This is a hack to use :to tag for absolute paths.
      path: "/http*",
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        window.open(to.fullPath.substring(1), '_blank');
        next(false)
      }
    })
  }
},
```

In layouts/default.vue:

```html
<v-list>
  <v-list-item
    v-for="(item, i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :to="item.to"
    router
    exact
  >
    <v-list-item-action>
      <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
    </v-list-item-action>
    <v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" />
    </v-list-item-content>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

This works in that it allows me to click on the link and it will open up it up in a new tab, unfortunately the app then goes to 404.  From the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) I read that `next(false)` should cancel the navigation request and send the user back to their previous page which is the desired behaviour.  But this does not seem to be happening and it is showing the error.vue page instead.

Do you know why this is happening and if there is a fix?

Comment: Keep it simple with something like this: `<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">My cool link</a>`

Comment: I would like to know why using next in the beforeEnter results in the navigation being cancelled but the content from layouts/error.vue is shown so I get a 404.  This does not seem like the correct behaviour for next(false) or similar.

Comment: I do agree that this looks like something is wrong here. But I'm not sure because not used of this kind of config (in `nuxt.config.js`). You could try making this guard in a page or layout and see how it reacts. Otherwise, console logging the state and checking the devtools may help for the routing. But still, why don't you use some simple `a` tags in this case?